# packages are deleted from netbeans after restarting PC

Tags: java, netbeans, package, project

i restarted my PC when i opened NETBEANS my already existing packages were missing. I tried to do restore deleted but it wasn't helpful.. any idea?

Comment: Are you sure they weren't simply hidden?

Comment: i can open my project GUI from windows search bar and it works fine but i cannot find the code. My all previous project's packages are gone

Comment: Did you try using file - > open project?

Comment: of course i did.. anyways the problem is solved my friend had its backup.

Comment: I asked because the first time I had that problem I couldn't figure it out and that solved it.